# Cannot find what I think is a memory leak in predator prey program

Tags: java, arraylist, memory-leaks

I have six classes for my program and I believe most of my code is correct, but when I go to run it no print statements happen and instead the program continues running forever without output. This causes a massive memory leak if I run the simulation for larger numbers (100+). I can't seem to find what the problem is but the code just won't properly execute.

**** (where I execute the program from and where I think the error is)

```
import java.util.*;
public class {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        SubSim simulate=new SubSim();
        ArrayList<Wolf>WolfArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Moose>MooseArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Grass>GrassArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0;i<simulate.getInitialWolves();i++){
            WolfArrayList.add(new Wolf(simulate));
        }
        for (int i=0;i<simulate.getInitialMoose();i++){
            MooseArrayList.add(new Moose(simulate));
        }
        for (int i=0;i<simulate.getMaxX();i++){
            for (int j=0;i<simulate.getMaxY();j++){
                int grassroll=(int)(Math.random()*5);
                if (grassroll==1||grassroll==2||grassroll==3||grassroll==4){
                    GrassArrayList.add(new Grass(simulate,i,j,2));
                }
                else{
                    GrassArrayList.add(new Grass(simulate,i,j,0));
                }
            }
        }
        simulate.setGrassArrayList(GrassArrayList);
        simulate.setMooseArrayList(MooseArrayList);
        simulate.setWolfArrayList(WolfArrayList);
        System.out.println("Ticks        Wolves          Moose");
        for(int i=1;i<=20;i++){
            System.out.printf("%d           %d          %d\n",(i-1),simulate.getWolfPop(),simulate.getMoosePop());
            simulate.run();
        }
    }
}
```

** Class**

```
    import java.util.*;
public class  extends Simulator{
//making private variables
private ArrayList<Grass> GrassArrayList;
private ArrayList<Moose> MooseArrayList;
private ArrayList<Wolf> WolfArrayList;
//using the animals move method
@Override
public void animalsMove() {
    for (int i = 0; i < WolfArrayList.size(); i++) {
        WolfArrayList.get(i).move();
        WolfArrayList.get(i).setEnergy(WolfArrayList.get(i).getEnergy()-getMovementCost());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < MooseArrayList.size(); i++) {
        MooseArrayList.get(i).move();
        MooseArrayList.get(i).setEnergy(MooseArrayList.get(i).getEnergy()-getMovementCost());

    }
}
//using the animals die method
@Override
public void animalsDie(){
        int WolfArraySize=WolfArrayList.size();
        for (int i=0;i<WolfArraySize;i++) {
            if (WolfArrayList.get(i).getEnergy() <= 0){
                WolfArrayList.remove(i);
                WolfArraySize = WolfArrayList.size();
            }
        }
    int MooseArraySize=MooseArrayList.size();
    for (int i=0;i<WolfArraySize;i++){
        if (MooseArrayList.get(i).getEnergy() <= 0){
            MooseArrayList.remove(i);
            MooseArraySize = MooseArrayList.size();
        }
    }
}
//using animals eat method
@Override
public void animalsEat() {
    for (int i = 0; i < WolfArrayList.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < MooseArrayList.size(); j++) {
            if (MooseArrayList.get(j).getLocationX() == WolfArrayList.get(i).getLocationX() && MooseArrayList.get(j).getLocationY() == WolfArrayList.get(i).getLocationY()) {
                MooseArrayList.remove(j);
                WolfArrayList.get(i).eat();
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < MooseArrayList.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < GrassArrayList.size(); j++) {
            if (MooseArrayList.get(i).getLocationX() == GrassArrayList.get(j).getXcord() && MooseArrayList.get(i).getLocationY() == GrassArrayList.get(j).getYcord()) {
                MooseArrayList.remove(j);
                WolfArrayList.get(i).eat();
            }
        }
    }
}
//using animals reproduce method
@Override
public void animalsReproduce(){
    for (int i=0;i<WolfArrayList.size();i++){
        if (WolfArrayList.get(i).getEnergy() >= 100) {
            Wolf puppy = (Wolf) WolfArrayList.get(i).reproduce();
            WolfArrayList.add(puppy);
            WolfArrayList.get(i).setEnergy(getInitialEnergy());
        }
    }
    for (int i=0;i<MooseArrayList.size();i++) {
        if (MooseArrayList.get(i).getEnergy() >= 100) {
            Moose calf = (Moose) MooseArrayList.get(i).reproduce();
            MooseArrayList.add(calf);
            MooseArrayList.get(i).setEnergy(getInitialEnergy());
        }
    }
}
//using grass grows method
@Override
public void grassGrows(){
        for(int i=0;i<GrassArrayList.size();i++){
            if (GrassArrayList.get(i).getLength()>0){
                GrassArrayList.get(i).setLength((int)(GrassArrayList.get(i).getLength()+getGrassGrowthRate()));
            }
            //making shorthand instanced variables
            int xcord=GrassArrayList.get(i).getXcord();
            int ycord=GrassArrayList.get(i).getYcord();
            if(GrassArrayList.get(i).getLength()>=10){
                for (int j=0;j<GrassArrayList.size();j++){
                    //checking area around tall grass to place seeds
                    if(xcord==GrassArrayList.get(j).getXcord() && ycord+1==GrassArrayList.get(j).getYcord() || xcord-1==GrassArrayList.get(j).getXcord() && ycord+1==GrassArrayList.get(j).getYcord() || xcord-1==GrassArrayList.get(j).getXcord() && ycord==GrassArrayList.get(j).getYcord() || xcord-1==GrassArrayList.get(j).getXcord() && ycord-1==GrassArrayList.get(j).getYcord() || xcord==GrassArrayList.get(j).getXcord() && ycord-1==GrassArrayList.get(j).getYcord() || xcord+1==GrassArrayList.get(j).getXcord() && ycord-1==GrassArrayList.get(j).getYcord() || xcord+1==GrassArrayList.get(j).getXcord() && ycord==GrassArrayList.get(j).getYcord() || xcord+1==GrassArrayList.get(j).getXcord() && ycord+1==GrassArrayList.get(j).getYcord()){
                        GrassArrayList.get(j).setLength((int)(GrassArrayList.get(j).getLength()+getGrassGrowthRate()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
//using the run method
@Override
public void run(){
    tick();
}
public int getMoosePop(){
    return MooseArrayList.size();
}
public int getWolfPop(){
    return WolfArrayList.size();
}
public ArrayList<Grass> getGrassArrayList() {
    return GrassArrayList;
}
public void setGrassArrayList(ArrayList<Grass> grassArrayList) {
    GrassArrayList = grassArrayList;
}
public ArrayList<Moose> getMooseArrayList() {
    return MooseArrayList;
}
public void setMooseArrayList(ArrayList<Moose> mooseArrayList) {
    MooseArrayList = mooseArrayList;
}
public ArrayList<Wolf> getWolfArrayList() {
    return WolfArrayList;
}
public void setWolfArrayList(ArrayList<Wolf> wolfArrayList) {
    WolfArrayList = wolfArrayList;
}
}
```

** Class**

```
public class extends {
private int movewolf;
public Wolf(Simulator simulator){
    super(simulator);
}
@Override
public void eat(){
    setEnergy((getEnergy()+getSimulator().getEnergyGainFromEatingMoose()));
}
@Override
public Animal reproduce(){
    Wolf wolf=new Wolf(getSimulator());
    wolf.setLocationX(getSimulator().randomInt(getSimulator().getMaxX()));
    wolf.setLocationY(getSimulator().randomInt(getSimulator().getMaxY()));
    wolf.setEnergy(getSimulator().getInitialEnergy());
    return wolf;
}
@Override
public Animal die(){
    return null;
}
@Override
public void move(){
    int moveX=(int)(Math.random()*2);
    int moveY=(int)(Math.random()*2);
    if (getLocationX()<getSimulator().getMaxX()&& getLocationX()>0 && getLocationY()<getSimulator().getMaxY()&& getLocationY()>0){
        if (moveX==1){
            this.movewolf=getLocationX()+1;
            setLocationX(movewolf);
        }
        else{
            this.movewolf=getLocationX()-1;
            setLocationX(movewolf);
        }
        if (moveY==1){
            this.movewolf=getLocationY()+1;
            setLocationY(movewolf);
        }
        else{
            this.movewolf=getLocationY()-1;
            setLocationY(movewolf);
        }
    }
    else if (getLocationX()==getSimulator().getMaxX()){
        this.movewolf=getLocationX()-1;
        setLocationX(movewolf);
    }
    else if(getLocationX()==0){
        this.movewolf=getLocationX()+1;
        setLocationX(movewolf);
    }
    else if (getLocationY()==getSimulator().getMaxY()){
        this.movewolf=getLocationY()-1;
        setLocationY(movewolf);
    }
    else if (getLocationY()==0){
        this.movewolf=getLocationY()+1;
        setLocationY(movewolf);
    }
    else {
    }
}
}
```

** Class**

```
public class  extends Animal{
private int movemoose;
public Moose(Simulator simulator){
    super(simulator);
}
@Override
public void eat(){
    setEnergy((getEnergy()+getSimulator().getEnergyGainFromEatingGrass()));
}
@Override
public Animal reproduce(){
    Moose moose=new Moose(getSimulator());
    moose.setLocationX(getSimulator().randomInt(getSimulator().getMaxX()));
    moose.setLocationY(getSimulator().randomInt(getSimulator().getMaxY()));
    moose.setEnergy(getSimulator().getInitialEnergy());
    return moose;
}
@Override
public Animal die(){
    return null;
}
@Override
public void move(){
    int moveX=(int)(Math.random()*2);
    int moveY=(int)(Math.random()*2);
    if (getLocationX()<getSimulator().getMaxX()&& getLocationX()>0 && getLocationY()<getSimulator().getMaxY()&& getLocationY()>0){
        if (moveX==1){
            this.movemoose=getLocationX()+1;
            setLocationX(movemoose);
        }
        else{
            this.movemoose=getLocationX()-1;
            setLocationX(movemoose);
        }
        if (moveY==1){
            this.movemoose=getLocationY()+1;
            setLocationY(movemoose);
        }
        else{
            this.movemoose=getLocationY()-1;
            setLocationY(movemoose);
        }
    }
    else if (getLocationX()==getSimulator().getMaxX()){
        this.movemoose=getLocationX()-1;
        setLocationX(movemoose);
    }
    else if(getLocationX()==0){
        this.movemoose=getLocationX()+1;
        setLocationX(movemoose);
    }
    else if (getLocationY()==getSimulator().getMaxY()){
        this.movemoose=getLocationY()-1;
        setLocationY(movemoose);
    }
    else if (getLocationY()==0){
        this.movemoose=getLocationY()+1;
        setLocationY(movemoose);
    }
    else {
    }
}
}
```

** Class**

```
public class {
public Simulator getGrass(){
    return grass;
}
public void setGrass(Simulator grass){
    this.grass = grass;
}
public int getLength(){
    return length;
}
public void setLength(int length){
    this.length = length;
}
public int getInitialLength(){
    return initialLength;
}
public void setInitialLength(int initialLength){
    this.initialLength = initialLength;
}
public int getXcord(){
    return Xcord;
}
public void setXcord(int xcord){
    Xcord = xcord;
}
public int getYcord(){
    return Ycord;
}
public void setYcord(int ycord){
    Ycord = ycord;
}
private Simulator grass;
private int length;
private int initialLength=0;
private int Xcord;
private int Ycord;

public Grass(Simulator grass, int xcord, int ycord, int length){
    this.grass = grass;
    this.length = length;
    Xcord = xcord;
    Ycord = ycord;
    setLength(initialLength);
}
}
```

Comment: Any for loop never causes for-ever loop, if the limit is mentioned. I can see the limit i.e 2nd argument of for loop is given, so it will not cause issue. Is there any while loop in the classes mentioned ? and what is the value of simulate.getMaxX() and simulate.getMaxY()

Comment: maxX and maxY are the max values of the 30x30 grid everything happens on. I will add to the orignal post with the rest of the classes for more clarity

Comment: @MrunmayDeswandikar that's demonstrably not true: `for (int i = 0; true; ) {}` has a condition, but it's an infinite loop.

Comment: Yes right friend @AndyTurner ! just boolean can also be a condition ! Perfect

Comment: 1 up from my side ! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see a problem with the second line here:

```
for (int i=0;i<simulate.getMaxX();i++){
  for (int j=0;i<simulate.getMaxY();j++){
```

I think it should be `j<simulate.getMaxY()`

Comment: Do you remove remove the nested for loop entirely or simply replace `(int j=0;i<simulate.getMaxY();j++){` with `j<simulate.getMaxY();` I am either misunderstanding the proposed solution or I am entering it in wrong.

Comment: The line should be `for (int j=0; j<simulate.getMaxY(); j++){`. The previous condition you have never became false because the variable `i` from the outer loop wasn't updated in the inner loop. Only the condition tested in the second loop needs to be changed; the loops should remain unless there isn't other problem.

Comment: This fixes the memory leak issue! now however another has cropped up of "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 850, Size: 100
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
 at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:496)
 at SubSim.animalsEat(SubSim.java:56)
 at Simulator.tick(Simulator.java:96)
 at SubSim.run(SubSim.java:103)
 at SimRun.main(SimRun.java:35)" everytime i run the program the index value changes as well.

Comment: Yes, you would expect to get an index out of bounds error in a loop where you're reducing the size of the initilizing array.

Instead of using .remove(j) try to set the element at j to null and then do a pass AFTER the loop completes to remove all null elements in the array.

Comment: It also appears that in your animalsEat method, the mooses are eating themselves and not the grass.

Comment: yep, that was the problem! the program runs flawlessly now (excusing some rate tweeking!) thank you all!